# Search and Replace only in open files (netbeans)

Tags: netbeans

Anyone know if it's possible to search and replace in all opened files in netbeans? Can't seem to find the option if there even is one.

I'm using the Netbeans 6.9 PHP IDE

Comment: I sent a request to Netbeans in 2012 to add this feature to Netbeans 7.3 But they didn't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To search in open files press `CTRL+SHIFT+F` and in section `scope` select `Open Documents`.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

`CTRL+SHIFT+H`

This will open the Replace in Projects, where-in you can search and replace on files on all open projects, or on the selected project only.

Comment: i know of the various search functions in netbeans, but i can't seem to find the "search in open files" function/option. Searching through an entire project isn't what i'm looking for that the file filter in the 'search opened projects' panel isn't flexible enough to limit the files i want to search through.

Comment: -1.  This doesn't address the question, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

It's available in builds >= 7.4 from NetBeans. Not available in 7.3. I just got a status update message from NetBeans that they've added this feature.

1. Use Replace in Projects. Shortcut = <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Select Open Documents

[image: You can see how it looks likes here]

Comment: Latest build means >=7.4 in this case

Answer (score 8):

Open the file you want the replacements.
Press `Ctrl + H`
And them at the bottom you will see

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, only your answer works. I think most people are blind.

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can ... or at least you can do something very similar ...

Go to projects view and select multiple files (the files you have opened in this case). Then press CTRL+F and start searching in the selected nodes. It's not exactly 'opened files' but I think it's your best choice.

Hope that helps!

PD: CTRL + CLICK is a good method to select multiple files on Windows.

Comment: But selecting around 10 or 15 opened files from the project view takes time. I've also found this feature very helpful if we can search only in opened files. I sent a request to Netbeans about this before some months...

Answer (score 1):

This seems impossible in netbeans 6.9 and it hasn't been introduced in Netbeans 7 either.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible just the Rule mentioned.

*Check*  *Uncheck* the files and hit **replace** button on left hand side.

Comment: opened files is not the same as opened projects :)

Answer (score -1):

Select your files you want to find and replace in Project view ( Window > Projects )
Go to Edit > Replace In Projects...
In Replace in Projects window select "Selection" from "Scope" dropdown menu

Find and replace will be committed on your selected files in Projects view.

This is the way I found.