# How can I replace a string in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, replace, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search and Replace Entire Project (Netbeans)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans)

Other IDE's have a feature to find and replace something in code. I want this feature in Netbeans. I know there is the refactor feature, but that's only for variables. How can I find and replace text that isn't a variable name?

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted so the question can be improved upon, rather than sit idle.

Comment: Although it wasn't my downvote, I can fathom a guess. If you read the tooltip on the down arrow, it says "This question does not show any research effort." A quick Google search or a quick search in Stack Overflow turns up [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804427/search-and-replace-only-in-open-files-netbeans) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000376/search-and-replace-entire-project-netbeans) and [solutions](http://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

CTRL+SHIFT+H will open the replace dialogue where you can find+replace in any or all of your open projects.

Comment: If that takes care of your question, don't forget to select it! :)

Comment: I wanted to do it, but it needs some minutes ... Don't worry friend. ;)

Comment: I don't know why my question has a down vote

Comment: Heads up - make sure to select the appropriate option from the 'Scope' drop-down. Otherwise the find and replace will apply to all open projects, rather than just the current project or file.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> gives you the Find and Replace dialogue, as shown:

[image]

If you ever have trouble finding a certain function in Netbeans, one of the first places you can check is the list of [keyboard shortcuts](http://netbeans.org/project_downloads/www/shortcuts.pdf).